# MFMailComposer Email Results From Core Data

Tags: core-data, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Core data functions nicely.  What might be a code snippet to reference the results of the core data and insert into MFMailComposeViewController directly inline (not as an attachment) using isHTML = Yes...

Currently I use code similar to this style (from one of my other apps) (and works)... not sure how to call the core data results to do similar...

```
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p>Stats...</p>
<p><b>Laps Completed: %@</b></p><p>Goal: %@ laps</p>
<p>Time To Complete: %@ (h:m:s)</p>
<p>%f&#37 completion ratio</p>",
self.lapLabel.text, self.goal.text, self.timeLabel.text, 
(self.percentageDoughnut.percentage)*100];


    [mail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIActivityViewController with attaching file data from local storage, check below code

```
 let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)     
 activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view .                  
 activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.frame
 self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```